# При загрузке на amazon получаю не тот url

Tags: php, symfony2, amazon

```
$plainUrl  = $s3Client->getObjectUrl("crs-sbx", 'test.txt');    
http://crs-sbx.s3.amazonaws.com/test.txt need
https://s3.us-standard.amazonaws.com/crs-sbx/test.txt current
```

Answer (score 1):

Если я не ошибаюсь, то метод `getObjectUrl`, возвращает `url` для "внутреннего" использования и не предназначен для публичного использования.

К примеру, в нашем проекте, учитывая всю его специфику, у нас был сервис который сам генерировал ссылку, `вида http[s]://s[1-9].project.ru/{basket}/{key}/`